# iOS Share extension: Enable support for Apple Podcasts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have built a Share Extension for my iOS app. It works fine with all sorts of apps, like iTunes, Safari etc etc. I have enabled all the keys that are mentioned in the documentation using my extensions info.plist file:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```

However, my app still doesn't appear on the list of apps to share with when I try to share from the Apple Podcasts app. I get other apps to appear, Like Telegram and Trello, but not my app.

Is there anything special I need to do?

(The app is built with ReactNative, and contains Objective-C and Swift code. It is built against the iOS 13 SDK using XCode 12.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

So turns out some apps like Podcasts, BBC News etc. share in a number of attachments. Also, Podcasts requires all the options to be on even though it eventually only shares a URL. The way to get your app appear everywhere as a Share Extension is to allow all stuff with high counts:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsTextWithMinCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
<true />
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
<integer>999</integer>
```

This of course creates a new problem - what if you just don't want to support some types? E.g. when I remove `NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount` from the keys, my app doesn't appear on podcasts anymore. But I don't want people to be able to share local videos with my app. This means I now have to put extra logic into my share extension to test for what I actually want to process.